# Importar Tkinter vs code

Tags: python, vscode

no puedo importar tkinter desde vs code en ubuntu v18.4, instale la libreria y comprobe que funcione desde el terminal. Tengo python 3.6 y tkinter 8.6.
al importarla desde python me funciona y me muestra el cuadro, todo perfecto.

cuando lo hago desde vs code me reconoce la libreria(figura en el autocompletado del codigo) pero al momento de importarlo y ejecutarlo no puedo:

import tkinter
ventana = tkinter.Tk()

line 2, in 
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'
ese es el error.

Comment: De casualidad tenes en la carpeta de tu script un archivo llamado tkinter.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me a pasado hace escasas horas y ya lo e solucionado, simplemente estoy casi seguro de que el script de python que estar haciendo tiene como nombre "tkinter.py". Esto al parecer causa problemas con la librería, debes cambiarle el nombre, saludos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).